# Loading incorrect url in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

Can someone help me with this please. Each time I enter this url http://localhost/web/app_dev.php/activity1/ it doesn't go to this page but rather it loads this page http://localhost/web/app_dev.php/users/login. I am not seeing the reason why it's doing that. Even after rewriting the entity and controller.

**Entity**

```
    <?php

    namespace com\twcl\agripayrollBundle\Entity;


    /**
     * Activity1
     */
    class Activity1
    {
        /**
         * @Assert\NotBlank(message="The activity type must be entered.")
         * @var string
         * 
         */
        private $activitytype;

        /**
         * 
         * @var string
         * 
         * 
         */
        private $activitydesc;

        /**
         * @Assert\NotBlank(message="The activity date must be entered.")
         * @var \DateTime
         * 
         * 
         *
         */
        protected $activitydate;

        /**
         * @Assert\NotBlank(message="The activity quantity worked must be entered.")
         * @var number
         *

     */
    private $unitwork;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     */
    private $dateentered;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="The employee must be entered.")
     * @var integer
     * 
     */
    private $empid;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $transid;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="The payroll period must be entered.")
     * @var \com\twcl\agripayrollBundle\Entity\Payrollperiod
     */
    private $payrollperiodid;


    private $userid;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="The section must be entered.")
     * @var \com\twcl\agripayrollBundle\Entity\Section
     */
    private $sectionid;
    //@ORM\JoinColumn(name="description", referencedColumnName="id")
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="The rate code must be entered.")
     * @var \com\twcl\agripayrollBundle\Entity\Rate
     * 
     */
    private $ratecode;
    private $versionnumber;
    private $verifystate;

    public function getVerifystate() {
        return $this->verifystate;
    }

    public function setVerifystate($state) {
        $this->verifystate = $state;
    }

    public function setVersionnumber($versionnumber) {
        $this->versionnumber = $versionnumber;
    }

    public function getVersionnumber() {
        return $this->versionnumber;
    }

    /**
     * Set activitytype
     *
     * @param string $activitytype
     * @return Activity
     */
    public function setActivitytype($activitytype) {
        $this->activitytype = $activitytype;
    }

    /**
     * Get activitytype
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getActivitytype() {
        return $this->activitytype;
    }

    /**
     * Set activitydesc
     *
     * @param string $activitydesc
     * @return Activity
     */
    public function setActivitydesc($activitydesc) {
        $this->activitydesc = $activitydesc;
    }

    /**
     * Get activitydesc
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getActivitydesc() {
        return $this->activitydesc;
    }

    /**
     * Set activitydate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $activitydate
     * @return Activity
     */
    public function setActivitydate($activitydate) {
        $this->activitydate = $activitydate;
    }

    /**
     * Get activitydate
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getActivitydate() {
        return $this->activitydate;
    }

    /**
     * Set unitwork
     *
     * @param integer $unitwork
     * @return Activity
     */
    public function setUnitwork($unitwork) {
        $this->unitwork = $unitwork;
    }

    /**
     * Get unitwork
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getUnitwork() {
        return $this->unitwork;
    }

    /**
     * Set dateentered
     *
     * @param \DateTime $dateentered
     * @return Activity
     */
    public function setDateentered($dateentered) {
        $this->dateentered = $dateentered;
    }

    /**
     * Get dateentered
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getDateentered() {
        return $this->dateentered;
    }

    /**
     * Set empid
     * @param integer $empid
     * @return Activity
     * 
     *  
     */
    public function getEmpid() {
        return $this->empid;
    }

    /**
     * Get empid
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function setEmpid($empid) {
        $this->empid = $empid;
    }

    /**
     * Get transid
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getTransid() {
        return $this->transid;
    }

    /**
     * Set payrollperiodid
     *
     * @param \com\twcl\agripayrollBundle\Entity\Payrollperiod $payrollperiodid
     * @return Activity
     */
    public function setPayrollperiodid(\com\twcl\agripayrollBundle\Entity\Payrollperiod $payrollperiodid = null) {
        $this->payrollperiodid = $payrollperiodid;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get payrollperiodid
     *
     * @return \com\twcl\agripayrollBundle\Entity\Payrollperiod 
     */
    public function getPayrollperiodid() {
        return $this->payrollperiodid;
    }

    /**
     * Set userid
     *
     * @param \com\twcl\agripayrollBundle\Entity\Users $userid
     * @return Activity
     */
    public function setUserid(\com\twcl\agripayrollBundle\Entity\Users $userid) {
        $this->userid = $userid;
    }

    /**
     * Get userid
     *
     * @return \com\twcl\agripayrollBundle\Entity\Users 
     */
    public function getUserid() {
        return $this->userid;
    }

    /**
     * Set sectionid
     *
     * @param \com\twcl\agripayrollBundle\Entity\Section $sectionid
     * @return Activity
     */
    public function setSectionid(\com\twcl\agripayrollBundle\Entity\Section $sectionid = null) {
        $this->sectionid = $sectionid;
    }

    /**
     * Get sectionid
     *
     * @return \com\twcl\agripayrollBundle\Entity\Section 
     */
    public function getSectionid() {
        return $this->sectionid;
    }

    //protected $sectionIdOnly;

    public function getSectionIdOnly() {
        $id = null;
        $section = $this->getSectionid();

        if ($section!=null){
            $id=$this->getSectionid()->getId();
        }
        return $id;
    }

    public function setSectionIdOnly ($empty) {

    }

    public function getFarmNameOnly() {
        return $this->farmNameOnly;
    }

    protected $farmNameOnly;

    public function setFarmNameOnly($farmName) {
        return $this->farmNameOnly = $farmName;
    }

    /**
     * Set ratecode
     *
     * @param \com\twcl\agripayrollBundle\Entity\Rate $ratecode
     * @return Activity
     */
    public function setRatecode(\com\twcl\agripayrollBundle\Entity\Rate $ratecode = null) {
        $this->ratecode = $ratecode;
    }

    /**
     * Get ratecode
     *
     * @return \com\twcl\agripayrollBundle\Entity\Rate 
     */
    public function getRatecode() {
        return $this->ratecode;
    }

    /**
     * Return an Activity as a String
     * @return string
     */
    public function __toString() {
        return  strval($this->getTransid());
    }

    /**
     * @Assert\Callback
     * validation that ensures: activities can only be entered for days within the payroll period.
     */
    public function constraint_within_payroll_period(\Symfony\Component\Validator\Context\ExecutionContextInterface $context) {

        /* startDate<=activitydate<=endDate */
        $startdate_diff = $this->activitydate->diff($this->payrollperiodid->getstartDate(), false);
        $endate_diff = $this->activitydate->diff($this->payrollperiodid->getendDate(), false);
//        var_dump($endate_diff);
//        echo '<br/>';
//        var_dump($endate_diff->invert);
//        echo' | ';
//        var_dump($endate_diff->days);
//        die();
        if (
                ($startdate_diff->invert == 0 && $startdate_diff->days > 0) ||
                ($endate_diff->invert == 1 && $endate_diff->days > 0 )
        ) {
            $context->buildViolation('Activities can only be entered for dates within the payroll period.')
                    ->atPath('activitydate')
                    ->addViolation();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @Assert\Callback
     * validation that ensures: The duration of an activity cannot go beyond 24hrs.
     */
    public function constraint_capped_duration(\Symfony\Component\Validator\Context\ExecutionContextInterface $context) {

        if (
                strcmp(trim($this->activitytype), 'Hourly') == 0 &&
                $this->unitwork > 24
        ) {
            $context->buildViolation('The duration of an hourly activity cannot go beyond 24hrs.')
                    ->atPath('unitwork')
                    ->addViolation();
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
    <?php

    namespace com\twcl\agripayrollBundle\Controller;

    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
    use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
    use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
    use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
    use com\twcl\agripayrollBundle\Entity\Activity1;
    use com\twcl\agripayrollBundle\Form\Activity1Type;

    /**
     * Activity1 controller.
     *
     * @Route("/activity1")
     */
    class Activity1Controller extends Controller
    {

        /**
         * Lists all Activity1 entities.
         *
         * @Route("/", name="activity1")
         * @Method("GET")
         * @Template()
         */
        public function indexAction()
        {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            $entities = $em->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Activity1')->findAll();

            return array(
                'entities' => $entities,
            );
        }
        /**
         * Creates a new Activity1 entity.
         *
         * @Route("/", name="activity1_create")
         * @Method("POST")
         * @Template("comtwclagripayrollBundle:Activity1:new.html.twig")
         */
        public function createAction(Request $request)
        {
            $entity = new Activity1();
            $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
            $form->handleRequest($request);

            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $em->persist($entity);
                $em->flush();

                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('activity1_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
            }

            return array(
                'entity' => $entity,
                'form'   => $form->createView(),
            );
        }

        /**
         * Creates a form to create a Activity1 entity.
         *
         * @param Activity1 $entity The entity
         *
         * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
         */
        private function createCreateForm(Activity1 $entity)
        {
            $form = $this->createForm(new Activity1Type(), $entity, array(
                'action' => $this->generateUrl('activity1_create'),
                'method' => 'POST',
            ));

            $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create'));

            return $form;
        }

        /**
         * Displays a form to create a new Activity1 entity.
         *
         * @Route("/new", name="activity1_new")
         * @Method("GET")
         * @Template()
         */
        public function newAction()
        {
            $entity = new Activity1();
            $form   = $this->createCreateForm($entity);

            return array(
                'entity' => $entity,
                'form'   => $form->createView(),
            );
        }

        /**
         * Finds and displays a Activity1 entity.
         *
         * @Route("/{id}", name="activity1_show")
         * @Method("GET")
         * @Template()
         */
        public function showAction($id)
        {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            $entity = $em->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Activity1')->find($id);

            if (!$entity) {
                throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Activity1 entity.');
            }

            $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

            return array(
                'entity'      => $entity,
                'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
            );
        }

        /**
         * Displays a form to edit an existing Activity1 entity.
         *
         * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="activity1_edit")
         * @Method("GET")
         * @Template()
         */
        public function editAction($id)
        {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            $entity = $em->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Activity1')->find($id);

            if (!$entity) {
                throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Activity1 entity.');
            }

            $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
            $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

            return array(
                'entity'      => $entity,
                'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
                'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
            );
        }

        /**
        * Creates a form to edit a Activity1 entity.
        *
        * @param Activity1 $entity The entity
        *
        * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
        */
        private function createEditForm(Activity1 $entity)
        {
            $form = $this->createForm(new Activity1Type(), $entity, array(
                'action' => $this->generateUrl('activity1_update', array('id' => $entity->getId())),
                'method' => 'PUT',
            ));

            $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Update'));

            return $form;
        }
        /**
         * Edits an existing Activity1 entity.
         *
         * @Route("/{id}", name="activity1_update")
         * @Method("PUT")
         * @Template("comtwclagripayrollBundle:Activity1:edit.html.twig")
         */
        public function updateAction(Request $request, $id)
        {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            $entity = $em->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Activity1')->find($id);

            if (!$entity) {
                throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Activity1 entity.');
            }

            $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
            $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
            $editForm->handleRequest($request);

            if ($editForm->isValid()) {
                $em->flush();

                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('activity1_edit', array('id' => $id)));
            }

            return array(
                'entity'      => $entity,
                'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
                'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
            );
        }
        /**
         * Deletes a Activity1 entity.
         *
         * @Route("/{id}", name="activity1_delete")
         * @Method("DELETE")
         */
        public function deleteAction(Request $request, $id)
        {
            $form = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
            $form->handleRequest($request);

            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $entity = $em->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Activity1')->find($id);

                if (!$entity) {
                    throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Activity1 entity.');
                }

                $em->remove($entity);
                $em->flush();
            }

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('activity1'));
        }

        /**
         * Creates a form to delete a Activity1 entity by id.
         *
         * @param mixed $id The entity id
         *
         * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
         */
        private function createDeleteForm($id)
        {
            return $this->createFormBuilder()
                ->setAction($this->generateUrl('activity1_delete', array('id' => $id)))
                ->setMethod('DELETE')
                ->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Delete'))
                ->getForm()
            ;
        }
    }
```

**Security.yml**

```
# you can read more about security in the related section of the documentation
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html
security:
    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#encoding-the-user-s-password

encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: 
        algorithm: bcrypt
        cost: 12

    com\twcl\agripayrollBundle\Entity\Users: 
        algorithm: sha512
        encode_as_base64: true

#            iterations: 5000            
    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#hierarchical-roles
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_VIEW_DATA_OWNER_2: ROLE_USER
        ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        administrators:
#            entity: {class: comtwclagripayrollBundle:Users, property: username}
            entity: {class: comtwclagripayrollBundle:Users}
#        in_memory:
#            memory:
#                users:
#                    user:  { password: $2a$12$s3OoYvNBLWjQuW.k76iRoOkdhEfHkU4ARYdkg9cMLKsZRcUPVV3o2, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ] }
#                    admin: { password: adminpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }

    # the main part of the security, where you can set up firewalls
    # for specific sections of your app
    firewalls:
        default:
            anonymous: ~
            http_basic: ~
            form_login:
                login_path: /users/login
                check_path: /users/login_check
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            logout:
                path: /users/logout
                target: activity_main
                invalidate_session: false
                delete_cookies: 
                    a: {path: null, domain: null}
                    b: {path: null, domain: null}
            anonymous: ~
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        # the login page has to be accessible for everybody
        demo_login:
            pattern:  ^/demo/secured/login$
            security: false

        # secures part of the application
        demo_secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/demo/secured/
            # it's important to notice that in this case _demo_security_check and _demo_login
            # are route names and that they are specified in the AcmeDemoBundle
            form_login:
                check_path: _demo_security_check
                login_path: _demo_login
            logout:
                path:   _demo_logout
                target: _demo
            #anonymous: ~
            #http_basic:
            #    realm: "Secured Demo Area"

    # with these settings you can restrict or allow access for different parts
    # of your application based on roles, ip, host or methods
    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#security-book-access-control-matching-options
    access_control:
        #- { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}
        - { path: ^/activity/main, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}
#        - { path: ^/activity/new, roles: ROLE_USER } 
        - { path: ^/activity, roles: ROLE_USER}
```

**Routing.yml**

```
comtwclagripayroll:
    resource: "@comtwclagripayrollBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
```

**Activity1Repository**

```
   <?php

namespace com\twcl\agripayrollBundle;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;


class Activity1Repository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findOverlappingWithRange(\DateTime $startDate, \DateTime $endDate)
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('e');

        $expr1 = $qb->expr()->andX('e.startDate < :endDate AND e.endDate > :startDate');
        $expr2 = $qb->expr()->andX('e.endDate > :startDate AND e.startDate < :endDate');
        $orExpr = $qb->expr()->orX($expr1, $expr2);

        return $qb->andWhere($orExpr)
            ->setParameter('startDate', $startDate)
            ->setParameter('endDate', $endDate)
            ->getQuery()
            ->execute()
        ;
    }
}
```

**ActivityType**

```
    <?php

namespace com\twcl\agripayrollBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class ActivityType extends AbstractType {

    protected $employeeList;
    protected $formstate;

    public function setEmployeeList($emplist) {
        $this->employeeList = $emplist;
    }

    public function getEmployeeList() {
        return $this->employeeList;
    }

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
                ->add('payrollperiodid', 'entity', array(
                    'label' => 'Payroll Period',
                    'class' => 'comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollperiod',
                    'query_builder' => function(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository $er) {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('p')
                                ->orderBy('p.startDate', 'ASC');
//                                ->where('p.state=1');
                    }
                        )
                )
                ->add('activitydate', 'datetime', array(
                    'label' => 'Activity Date',
                        /* 'data' => new \DateTime() */                        )
                )
                ->add('empsearch', 'text', array('mapped' => false, 'label' => 'Employee Id', 'required' => false))
                ->add('empid', 'choice', array('label' => 'Employee', 'choice_list' => $this->getEmployeeList())
                )
                ->add('sectionsearch', 'text', array('mapped' => false, 'label' => 'Section Code', 'required' => false))
                ->add('sectionid', 'entity', array(
                    'attr' => array('class' => 'activity_section_id_select_field'),
                    'label' => 'Section',
                    'data_class' => null,//'com\twcl\agripayrollBundle\Entity\Section',
                    'class' => 'comtwclagripayrollBundle:Section',
                    'query_builder' => function(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('s')
                        ->innerJoin('s.farmid', 'f')
                        ->addOrderBy('f.name')
//                                ->addOrderBy('s.quadrant')
                        ->addOrderBy('s.id')
                ;
            }
                        )
                )
                ->add('ratecode', 'entity', array(
                    'label' => 'Rate Code & Unit of Measure',
                    'class' => 'comtwclagripayrollBundle:Rate',
                    'query_builder' => function(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository $er) {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('r')
                                ->orderBy('r.ratecode');
                    }
                        )
                )
                ->add('activitytype', 'entity', array('label' => 'Activity Type', 'class' => 'comtwclagripayrollBundle:Acttype',)
                )
                ->add('unitwork', 'number', array('label' => 'Units Worked', 'required' => true,))
                ->add('activitydesc', 'text', array('label' => 'Comments', 'required' => false))
                ->add('versionnumber', 'hidden')
                ->add('sectionIdOnly', 'hidden')
                ->add('farmNameOnly', 'hidden');
//                ->add('dateentered', 'datetime', array('data' => new \DateTime(), 'read_only' => true))
//                ->add('userid');
//        $builder->addEventListener(\Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function(\Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent $event) {
//            $activity = $event->getData();
//            $form = $event->getForm();
//
////            if (isset($farm)) {
//
//            $form->add('sectionIdOnly', 'hidden')
//                    ->add('farmNameOnly', 'hidden');
////            }
//        });
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'com\twcl\agripayrollBundle\Entity\Activity',
            'cascade_validation' => true,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName() {
        return 'com_twcl_agripayrollbundle_activity';
    }

}
```

Comment: Please link your **app/config/security.yml** file

Comment: Please post your `app/config/security.yml`

Comment: ok I have placed it in the question

Comment: path: ^/activity, roles: ROLE_USER problem here no ? change the roles here to anonymously (maybe i'm wrong i don't use symfony)

Comment: you redirect all path starting with /activity which is not authentified to the login path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the last row of `security.yml` you are telling Symfony that every URL starting with `/activity` requires the user to be authenticated and have `ROLE_USER`.

If you aren't authenticated you are redirected to login page by the framework.

Comment: What if I don't want that then I should just remove it?

Comment: if you don't need to be authentificate to go there yes you should remove it

Comment: @buju yes you can. Remember to clean the cache if you are in prod environment

Comment: When I go onto http://localhost/web/app_dev.php/activity1/1/edit, it does the samething and I have removed it

Comment: @buju ok but that's another controller, post it or please post your `app/config/routing.yml`

Comment: It is the same controller

Comment: @buju post `Activity1Type` and `Activity1Repository`

Comment: @buju mmhm all looks right. How do you generate the view?

Comment: Hey it's fine now thank you. Could you assist me with another question, I know to do it in sql but not in doctrine